# Dividing two dictionaries values one by the other when values can be `None`

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have two dictionaries with the same keys but different values:

```
one = {"a":8, "b":10, "c":"N/A"}
two = {"a":2, "b":2, "C":100}
```

I want to divide the values and name a new key to get this:

```
three = {"a_ratio":4, "b_ratio":5, "c_ratio":"N/A"}
```

The thing where I need real help is when a value in one of the dictionaries is `None`. In that case I need the resultant value to be `None`.

It would be great if someone could do the same using `dictionary comprehension` (if possible).

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use dict comprehension, assuming all of the keys are present in both dictionaries:

```
three = { key +"_ratio" : int(one[key] / two[key]) for key in one.keys() }
```

Output:

```
>>> three
{'a_ratio': 4, 'b_ratio': 5}
```

Comment: ok thats great! but i have a second problam as some keys dont have a value rather a "N/A" string. I these case i need the ratio value to be "N/A" as well. Is there a solution for that? i dont want to loss the "N/A"s..

Comment: @ניסןפייגין Please don't ask follow-up questions in comments. If you have another problem, try to do some research first, and if you're still stuck ask a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

This will help:

```py
three = {key+"_ratio":one[key]/two[key] for key in one.keys()}
```

If you want the values to be integers only, you can simply use `//` (integer division) instead of `/`

Answer (score 0):

If `one` and `two` don't have all their keys in common, you can do this:

```
one = {"a":8, "b":10}
two = {"a":2, "b":2}

three = {f"{key}_ratio": one[key] / two[key] for key in one.keys() & two.keys()}
```

Result of `three`:

```
{'b_ratio': 5.0, 'a_ratio': 4.0}
```

Comment: @paradoxlover This is actually an answer that *is* different from yours.

Comment: @paradoxlover `one.keys() & two.keys()` makes a big difference here.

Comment: I meant how is it better? You are using keys from both the dictionaries although the keys are common.

Comment: @paradoxlover Your answer will throw an error if `two` has keys not contained in `one`, mine does not.

Comment: But that is not the case right... Talking of cases, you can assume hundreds of exceptions and keep handling them all day. But here what is important is to answer what the OP needs. If there was  such a case as u mention, OP should have mentioned that. SIMPLE!! Since he did not mention anything as such, it's of no use assuming cases and posting answers saying that it is different or better.

Comment: OP clearly states _two dictionaries with the same keys_